# Assign while loop results to array values

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

In switching from authorize.net's SIM method over to AIM method of handling credit card transactions the way a LINE-ITEM is sent to the processor is different. In the (SIM) version, I could send line items by looping through the results and echoing the hidden INPUT field and its values with appropriate separators like this:

```
$qw = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM XCart WHERE Buyer_ID='xyz' LIMIT 30");
$ctr=0;
while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($qw))
{
    ++$ctr; 
echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"x_line_item\" value=\"".$list['Item_Number']."<|>".substr($list['Item_Title'], 0, 30)."<|><|>".$list['Item_Qty']."<|>".$list['Item_Price']."<|>Y\">\n";
}
```

But now, under the AIM method, the line items are assigned to an ARRAY, I am still in the infancy stages of PHP, but when I try to place a WHILE LOOP inside of the array similar to the above method, it gives me errors:

```
$line_items = array( WHILE LOOP INSIDE HERE);
```

The output of the AIM method should output as shown below, but I'm not sure how to loop through the results in a manner that gives me this output below. I'm missing something and/or doing it wrong, but any help would be appreciated.

```
$line_items = array(
    "item1<|>golf balls<|><|>2<|>18.95<|>Y",
    "item2<|>golf bag<|>Wilson golf carry bag, red<|>1<|>39.99<|>Y",
    "item3<|>book<|>Golf for Dummies<|>1<|>21.99<|>Y"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$qw = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM XCart WHERE Buyer_ID='xyz' LIMIT 30");
$ctr=0;
$line_items = array();
while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($qw))
{
$line_items[] = $list['Item_Number']."<|>".substr($list['Item_Title']."<|>".$list['Item_Qty']."<|>".$list['Item_Price']."<|>";
}
```

something like this?

Be carefully, honestly you shouldn't be messing with payment system if you don't know anythign about PHP.....to learn more learn more about php arrays @ http://php.net/array

Comment: Wasn't able to get the output to be accepted by the payment API using what you provided - but thank you anyway. In response to your comment about the payment system: I'm new/learning, not completely knowledgless, having said that - it was integrated and working fine until they forced members to use a different API than was already in use.